# Invalid Pointer while realloc()

Tags: c, realloc

*Caller Function:*

```
void caller_func(){
    char *c = malloc(strlen("Hi") + 1);
    c = "Hi"; //c is a pointer char*
    char **s = &oi; //s is a pointer to a pointer: char **;
    called_func(s, 3, 'A');
}
```

*Called Function*

```
void called_func(char **s, int p, char c){
        char *w = *s; //w = oi ?!
        size_t len = strlen(w);
        if(w[p] == '\0'){
           w = realloc(w, len+1); // ERROR HERE. INVALID POINTER
        }  
    }
```

I know that I should use a temporary variable. That way, if the realloc fails, I still free the original value. It's just a test.
It gives me the `Invalid Pointer 0x0000232***` error.

Comment: 1. When you assign to a variable, you change its value. 2. So when you assign to a pointer you change its value. 3. But the value of a pointer is an address. It is the address in memory that the pointer points to. 4. So when you assign to a pointer, you change the address it points to. 5.  `c` is a pointer. When you assign to `c` (i.e. you do `c =` anything), it stops pointing to what it was pointing to earlier and starts pointing towards the new address you assigned to it. So, `c = "Hi"` makes it point to a new address than it was pointing to earlier.

Comment: You know that we don't even know what `oi` is, don't you? So the whole snippet is nonsense. and overall, you don't have to allocate memory, let a pointer point to it and after that let the pointer point to a string literal what effectivley lets you use track of the allocated mem block.

Comment: Also: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **desired behavior**, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions **without a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. -> I can't reproduce the error from that snippet. I just can see other errors/fails. so this is offtopic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following:

```
strcpy(c, "Hi"); // Instead of c = "Hi". Using strcpy() you are copying into   

                 // the memory allocated via malloc().
```

realloc() will now work as expected, since 'w' will now be pointing to the

memory initially allocated via malloc().

(Draw it on paper if it confuses you ... and you will quickly notice how 'c' points to a different location after you do c = "Hi";)

Comment: what to draw on a paper? and how should it help?

Comment: Why is that comment confusing ? Use a pen/pencil and paper & 'map' it out ... he has multiple pointers & pointers to pointers etc. in his functions ... writing things down on paper can help clear confusion.  Was the downvote bcos i said 'draw on paper' or bcos the content of my answer not useful ... ?

Comment: the downvote was, as we don't know what `oi` is we can just guess that has connection to `c` so overall we can jsut guess why `realloc()` fails. But overall we definetly can't resolv that to be the source of the stated error, what you are claiming. that's why -1. the pen n paper is not usefull INMHO as to draw it down you had to understand what is happening behind the scenes to do it right. And if he would be able to do so, he would probably don't even need to ask whats wrong with his snippet. so useless overall in my opinion.

Comment: You miss the point & are splitting hairs here. The point is to provide some feedback which he can use to solve his problem. In the absence of some information, a reasonable assumption can be made as to what he is trying to ask & an appropriate response given to help him. It is then his responsibility to read answers & use the information provided appropriately.

Comment: That's what comment's are for. Anyway: I wouldn't have downvoted if you didn't claim that realloc **WILL** work after using `strcpy()` because you simply can't know. Even if it might appear obvious.

Answer (score 4):

```
char *c = malloc(strlen("Hi") + 1);
```

You allocate 3 bytes.

```
c = "Ola"; //c is a pointer char*
```

You change c to point elsewhere and lose what you allocated earlier. Read about **strcpy**.

Also "Ola" (with null terminator) would not fit in a buffer of 3 bytes.

Comment: I'll test it now. Would `*c = "..."` have some difference ? Worked. Thanks

Comment: yes but it would not do what you expect. (it just copies the 'O'), use strcpy or strdup

Comment: c is of type char *. "crap" is of type char *. *c is of type char, hence it obviously cannot take "crap". I already said you should use strcpy. Now I also recommend you read your book about the C language.